# 3D wheel effect with list or scroll view

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need to create a list view that has a few key requirements

1. Infinite scroll of a fixed number of items (ie looping)
2. Multiple child item types (images, text, inputs)
3. Multiple child item heights
4. "3d" wheel look/feel. 2d perspective changes and shadowing/coloring should suffice

It needs to be iOS and Android compatible in Flutter.

I've tried the List Wheel Scroll View widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html) and am currently using Carousel Slider (https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider), but neither quite get the job done. List Wheel can't do interactive inputs or mixed child heights and the carousel can't do mixed heights or '3d'.

Has anybody created or come across something that might at least get me going in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

Currently playing with CustomScrollView with some success. It allows me to have multiple child heights and I ~think~ I'll be able to add some perspective to the children in the scroll listener.

What I can't figure out with CustomScrollView is how to get the looping/infinite scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I liked using the [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) package a while ago. Not sure if it supports mixed heights, but it has 3D effects. But it doesn't seem maintained, so I would try this null-saefty unofficial fork : [flutter_swiper_null_safety](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper_null_safety)

Comment: I would recommend using ```carousel_slider``` package instead.

Comment: Read OP's message until the end, he's using that package